# Error with adding records to SQL Server database (nvarchar)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dataset

I am trying to add records to a SQL Server database. The connection works fine for any other table except one.

This is my code:

```
private void saveCurrent()
{
    try
    // Save entry into the database.
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO entries VALUES (@Date, @Tags, @Entry, @User)";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tags", txtTags.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entry", richEntryBox.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", Form1.userName);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            isDirty = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error saving this entry:  " + exception.ToString());
    }
```

The error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x8-131904): Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

All of the columns are of type `nvarchar(50)` and `nvarchar(MAX)`. I am trying to enter just text information, no binaries. The dataset shows that the table has a "photos" column, but it can be null and I'm not using it (for some reason, I cannot get VS2017 to delete that column). I have altered the dataset to not include the "photos" field, but still receiving the error. Any push to the solution would be appreciated. A snap of the dataset is included here.

My dataset, in which I've removed the photos column:

[image: my dataset, in which I've removed the photos column]

--S

Comment: Seems to me that the first column is of type `DATE` isn't it? But the value you are trying to insert is a "String". That doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried specifying the data type for the field in question...the problem with "Addwithvalue" is that it tries to guess your data type

Comment: Actually what are the column types of each table column?

Comment: Any trigger involved?

Comment: The "date" field is not a standard date, it is custom and is text. I have specified that all the fields in the table are nvarchar - is that what you mean? No trigger involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database still has the `photos` field, you'll need to specify the columns for insertion explicitly.

So change your insert to:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO entries (date, tags, entry, user) VALUES (@Date, @Tags, @Entry, @User)";
```

In general, you want to be explicit with your insertions. What would happen if someone added a column after tags and before entry in the database? This would break your code.

Comment: Thank you - this has gotten me farther along. I have modified the query to match what you have listed, with the explicit insertion fields. Oddly enough, I'm now getting an error that says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

Comment: Thank you! I had an odd misspelling in there. Got that corrected, used your suggestion to explicitly add the fields,finally manage to drop the photos field from the DB and it works great. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help!